# How to fix program and NOT receive "Command Execution Failed" error message in Java?

Tags: java, netbeans

This is my first class and first time using Java. I also need to display 'Employee Name, Rate of Pay, Hours Worked, Overtime Worked, Gross Pay, Total amount of deductions, & Net Pay in the program as well.

```
package calculatepayprogram;

import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 * Calculate Pay Program
 * CPT 307: Data Structures & Algorithms
 * 7/5/2022
 */
public class CalculatePayProgram{
    
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        double RateOfPay;
        int HoursWorked;
        double GrossPay;
        double OvertimeHours;
        double OvertimePay;
        double NetPay;
        double TotalDeductions;
        String name;
        
        System.out.println("Enter Your Name: ");
        name = reader.nextLine();
        
        System.out.print("Enter Your Pay Per Hour: ");
        RateOfPay = reader.nextDouble();
        
        System.out.print("Enter Your Hours Worked: ");
        HoursWorked = reader.nextInt();
        
        System.out.print("Enter Your Overtime Hours Worked: ");
        OvertimeHours = reader.nextDouble();
        
        GrossPay = RateOfPay * HoursWorked;
        
        OvertimePay = OvertimeHours * 1.5 * RateOfPay;
        
        double Pay = OvertimePay + GrossPay;
        
        System.out.println("Your Gross Pay For This Week Will Be $" + Pay);
        
        double FederalTax = .15 * Pay;
        double StateTax = .0307 * Pay;
        double Medicare = .0145 * Pay;
        double SocialSecurity = .062 * Pay;
        double Unemployment = .0007 * Pay;
        double TotalDeduct = FederalTax + StateTax + Medicare + SocialSecurity + Unemployment;
        
        System.out.println("Your Total Deductions For This Week Will Be $" + TotalDeduct);
        
        NetPay = Pay - TotalDeduct;
        
        System.out.println("Your Net Pay For This Week Will Be $" + NetPay);
    }   
}
```

Comment: I don't get what's wrong?

Comment: Where are you getting the error? Any error logs?